# How can I extract data by matching rows?

Tags: r

I have two datraframes:

```
lat    lon   v1
41.57 -88.11 11
41.58 -88.12 12
42.57 -89.11 55
41.55 -88.31 12

lat    lon   v2
41.57 -88.41 77
41.58 -88.12 56
42.57 -89.11 73
41.55 -88.61 14
```

I want to use the Lat/Long value from first dataframe, match it with the second dataframe and extract the V2 values and add it to the first dataframe. Here, row 2 and 3 are common between the two.

Expected output

```
lat    lon   v1 v2
41.57 -88.11 11 NA
41.58 -88.12 12 56
42.57 -89.11 55 73
41.55 -88.31 12 NA
```

How can I do this? I know subsetting within a dataframe, but not when to match it across multiple dataframes.

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, by=c('lat','lon'), all.x=TRUE)`?

Comment: Will it ignore the extra data in second dataframe? I basically want to keep the number of rows as it exists in the first dataframe.

Comment: Read `?merge` and do some tests with the arguments.

Comment: `all.x=TRUE` will do a left join, meaning, it will keep the same number of rows in the data frame you specify first.